# Asyncio + Aiohttp socket.send() raised exception

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a very simple file server using Aiohttp:

```
import os.path
from os import listdir
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web
import aiohttp_jinja2
import jinja2

@aiohttp_jinja2.template('template2.html')
@asyncio.coroutine
def get(request):
  root = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
  files = [file_name for file_name in listdir(os.path.join(root,'files'))
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, 'files', file_name))]
  return {'files': files}

if __name__ == "__main__":

   app = web.Application()
   aiohttp_jinja2.setup(app, loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('/root/async'))

   app.router.add_route('GET', '/', get)
   app.router.add_static('/files/' , '/root/async/files')

   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   f = loop.create_server(app.make_handler(), '0.0.0.0', 8080)
   srv = loop.run_until_complete(f)
   print(' serving on ', srv.sockets[0].getsockname())
   try:
    loop.run_forever()
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

When I test it using siege tool with, for example, such command:

```
siege -c 1000 -b -t 60 http://127.0.0.1:8080/files/kilobytes15.test
```

It raises a lot of exceptions like this:

```
socket.send() raised exception
```

And the amount of data transferred is very small. I assume that the socket closes before the file is fully sent to the user. 
 I would be very appreciated for some suggestion. Thank you in advance!
UPD:

template2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Aiohttp Test Server</title></head>
</body>
<h3>List of files:</h3>
<ul>
{% for item in files %}
<li><a href="/files/{{ item }}">{{ item }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

/root/async directory contains template2.html and server script file(code mentioned at the start). /root/async/files directory contains some dummy files of 15b, 15kb and 15mb sizes.

UPD: the exception is not risen for small files.

Comment: Don't fully understand your situation, but in general you'll need your coroutines to contain a yield from statement so that asyncio can pass control back and forth to other coroutines. If it is a connection that you need to keep open for ongoing activity, then you'll likely want a while True loop which contains a yield from statement. The simplest case could be yield from asyncio.sleep()

Comment: Hi, I know about yield statement, but as I understand it is not necessary to do it in get method, because it is already implemented in aiohttp. Maybe the problem is in static file handler, because in documentation they mention that it is not for production purposes.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot run your example to reproduce the issue.
`template2.html` is missing as well as other files (I have no idea what is content of your `/root/async` folder).

Comment: Hi Andrew! I've added code of template2.html and explained, what files does directory /root/async contains.

Comment: I've made my own investigation. Appeared that siege sends a get request with "Connection: close" header. This works fine for the same functionality, written on Tornado framework.
I've changed the "Connection: close" header to "Connection: Keep-Alive". Now there is no problem with "socket.send() raised exception", but siege throws Segmentation fault.
I assume that aiohttp, on most connection executes directive "Connection: close" first and than trying to send data to already closed socket. Need to figure out where relevant code is located.